# Code Contracts + Sandcastle -- Any way to customize the exceptions section?

Tags: c#, documentation, code-contracts, sandcastle, xml-documentation

- I'm using Code Contracts ver: 1.4.40602.0
- I copied the necessary Content and Transforms files
- Sandcastle outputs the exceptions based upon my contract requirements

Example Code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Object obj)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null);
    }
}
```

Resulting output (in my documentation):

```
| Exception                       | Condition                       |
|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|
| System.ArgumentNullException    | obj == null                     |
```

This isn't *that* bad, however I wonder if there is a way to customize the text of the Condition? I attempted to add a user message `Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null, "obj is null.");`, however this did not solve anything.

In the past I had to write my own xml documentation section for exceptions. Am I going to have to do that again to get what I need?

---

Disclaimer: Since Code Contracts is (currently) a DevLabs project, this could change, but I'm wondering if it's already available right now... if not, I'll be sure to suggest it.

Answer (score 3):

With Code Contracts 1.4.51019.0 you may use the overload:

`Requires<TException>(bool condition, string userMessage)`

However, your message will be appended after "Precondition failed" followed by the unmatched condition. If Sandcastle doesn't recognize it, I believe that it's not a fault in Code Contracts, since the message appears correctly to me.